# Cannot find -libnetcdff.a when compiling

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I received this error at bash interface while compiling my Fortran source code to read a `netcdf` file.
I used `gfortran -o firstrd -I/use/local/include/ rdNetcdf.f90 -L/use/local/lib/ -libnetcdff.a` but it returns

```
/use/bin/ld: cannot find -libnetcdff.a
```

I followed your previous recommend syntax on this issue before. 
I saw `libnetcdff.a` in the directory `/use/local/lib` and not `/use/lib` directory.

Comment: Probably either use ```-L/use/local/lib/ -lnetcdff``` or ```/use/local/lib/libnetcdff.a``` instead of ```-L/use/local/lib/ -libnetcdff.a```

Comment: Directory ```use``` or ```usr```?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Use [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 0):

nc-config is a tool that comes with the netcdf library that provides information on the library's configuration, including how to compile and link programs that use netcdf. `nc-config --help` describes the tool's usage. Its output includes the lines:

`--fc          Fortran compiler
--fflags      flags needed to compile a Fortran program
--flibs       libraries needed to link a Fortran program`

In particular, run `nc-config --fc --fflags --flibs` on your system to find out how to compile and link Fortran programs that use netcdf.